# ABAP startRFC.exe UTF-8 diacritics text transfer

Tags: text, utf-8, abap

I have a function module (FM) in SAP and I call it externally using startRFC. The only output of FM is one internal table. This table has only 1 column of type char(100) and I need to get it to text file. StartRFC works well, but if there is diacritics (for example Czech language: ěščřžýáíé) instead of these characters only hashes # appear.

Have someone ever solved similar issue?

If I call the same algorithm manually and write strings on screen in SAP, everything is ok. But startRFC somehow destroys it. The problem may be in the data transfer between SAP and startRFC. But I don't know how this transfer works.

I found a solution but it is terribly slow. It converts string to hexadecimal string using "gcl_conv_to_x->write" and "gcl_conv_to_x->get_buffer" than calls "SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY" and you need a binary table. But it takes 5minutes to do all this stuff. Without this conversion my algorithm takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Problem solved.. My startRFC used as an input parameter a txt file containing values separated by 0D0A (new lines). This text file was used to create an internal table and FM used it. And these new lines were the reason of all the problems in combination of SCMS_TEXT_TO_BINARY + startRFC. In the input text-file lines must be separated just by 0A char ( "\n" in PHP ).

Comment: So not solved.. startRFC again added double 0D0A..

Answer (score 1):

So finally a solution...

You need to create XSTRING variable and fill it with your text. To convert STRING to XSTRING use FM: SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING.

Then you will need an internal table with row type BAPICONTEN. It already contains component (column) of type SDOK_SDATX (RAW 1022).
And you just append a new line to this table like this:

```
data: my_table_row LIKE LINE OF my_table.
my_table_row-line = my_xstring.
APPEND my_table_row INTO my_table.
```

This table (my_table) can be returned via RFC and will contain Cyrillic, German characters etc..

I am just a beginner, so do not ask me how to create the table, please :)

Comment: And the same if you want to get diacritics using RFC to SAP.